# A single word for "the space in between"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can be used instead of "the space in between"? I am looking for something general.

Few words I thought of are period, interspace, mezzanine.

For example:

> The space in between fear and love is filled with uncertainty.
>
> The space in between birth and death is life.
>
> The space in between knowing and believing is something.

I like the word mezzanine but I am not sure if it fits since by definition it relates to architecture. Interspace, on the other hand, sounds like something related to science fiction. Period is about time.

An example of how I would like to use it:

> [Word] of fear and love is filled with uncertainty.
> [The mezzanine] of fear and love is filled with uncertainty.
> [The interspace] of fear and love is filled with uncertainty.

Comment: *Gap*, perhaps? Please see the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and the checklist towards the end.

Comment: Thanks. I added some words I thought of and improved the examples.

Comment: You can drop *in* - just *between* is enough, in these examples.

Comment: *interim*, but only for the second example.

Comment: The word, "interval," is  a direct translation from Latin of "space between the walls."

Comment: Just "between"? "Between fear and love, there's uncertainty." "Between birth and death there's life." Or "betwixt" even.

Comment: Couldn't resist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiVav5nBmOE

Comment: I sounds poetic: **Life is the mezzanine between birth and death.**

Comment: You can also drop the **in** to make it flow a bit more smoothly.

Comment: Distance? "The distance between fear and love is filled with uncertainty"

Comment: It is interesting that in all your examples the word _space_ is used metaphorically. Your _life–death_ use case carries a strong suggestion of a transition, which seems to have influenced some of the answers; it is less clear whether you intend it in that way in _fear–love_ or _knowing–believing_. If it _is_ transitional, is a return possible? Perhaps you could tell us more about what sort of _space_ you are thinking of: is it the time between_A_ and _B_, the intermediate space on a spectrum of possibilities (which works with _fear–love_) or something else again? Or should it be quite general?

Comment: @GEdgar: poetic? In an ironic way perhaps, but it would sound a bit pretentious to me if too seriously meant. I think of the mezzanine as an annoying, distracting part in a shop between where I am and where I want to be!

Comment: @PJTraill good point. I am looking for the space of possibiities - a space that can be filled. I am not looking into time between A and B.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Interstice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interstice):

> a space that intervenes between things; especially :  one between
>   closely spaced things. Eg, *interstices of a wall*

Comment: *Interstice* is at least as obscure as *lacuna*, but without the poetry.

Comment: **Interstices** is the first word that came to my mind. I somehow have trouble "hearing" the singular form in my head and want to use it in the plural even when it's a single space. Perhaps this is because it's so often used to describe gaps between things that come in groups, such as bricks in a wall, cells, etc.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood - Yeah, it's almost always used in plural form, though I do hear/read the singular on rare occasions.

Comment: I love both lacuna and interstice. Lacuna has a nice ring to it and the meaning has no positive or negative connotation:
a gap or space, esp in a book or manuscript.

Interstice, on the other hand, emphasizes more in-betweenness and implies small space. I am divided which one to choose. If it is according to the rules of the site can the two answers be combined?

Comment: I would say that “especially between closely spaced things” is definitely part of my idea of interstice, and that it is to do with structures, so I do not agree with this suggestion.

Answer (score 18):

I suggest ***gap.*** It needs to be paired with *between.*

> The gap between fear and love is filled with uncertainty.

However, **space,** as used in your question, is at least as good.

Comment: Mind the *space in between*.

Answer (score 9):

They're somewhat poetic but "rift" or "void" have a visual quality to them that may help illustrate the point.

Comment: VOID is definitely the word that you are looking for.

Comment: Trouble is, 'void' is seen as an empty space.

Answer (score 9):

[Lacuna](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lacuna) is my favorite.

> a blank space or a missing part

Comment: Yeah I liked lacuna as well, it was my first thought.  But it's a bit obscure.

Comment: Lacunas are often around the periphery. In-betweeness is missing.

Comment: @PhilSweet Lacunae *are* the in-between that's missing. Or is that what you were trying to say?

Comment: This is nice but I'm not sure it works with the examples with what I assume is the intended meaning — it's explicitly a *lack* of something,

Answer (score 3):

*Abyss, hollow, cavity, valley, interval, lacuna, gulf, silence, caesura, division, ravine, vacuum* ... it all depends on what *image* you wish to convey, really.

Answer (score 3):

**Span** would be a noun that meets your requirement.

> the full extent, stretch, or reach of anything (Dictionary.com)

But I don't see how you can introduce it without the using a words like "between" or "from/to":

> The span from birth to death is life.
>
> The span between faith and knowing is curiosity. (*Surely that's better than "something"*)
>
> The span from fear to love is reconciliation. (*I don't know where you came up with "uncertainty":)*)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping with your OP, just "Between" as in:

- between fear and love is uncertainty.
- between birth and death is life.
- between knowing and believing is something.

Not as poetic, but this isn't a poetry site.

interstitial is a space between things, but doesn't flow with your OP.

Comment: “Not a poetry site” – I don’t see why we shouldn’t be open to requests for an appropriate word for a given context, which could indeed be poetry. But this question does not specify that, and I find this suggestion works better than many of the higher-voted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I came across another word that can be used. It is liminal often times liminal space:

> of, relating to, or being an intermediate state, phase, or condition:  in-between, transitional "in the liminal state between life and death" — Deborah Jowitt

Comment: Surely _liminal_ means on the (or pertaining to a) threshold? That is certainly what [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=liminal) thinks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for space, and even specifically space between things, but I can't think of any nouns that work nicely without a preposition as well — either "between" or "of" or *something*. However, in your example of how you want to use the word, you *do* use "of", so maybe that's okay.

Therefore, I have a suggestion you *almost* have yourself. Interspace *is* a word, but I agree that it's not very pretty. Mezzanine is prettier but does make me think "mall food court". But, there's also ***intermezzo*** — this is a word from the arts, and has a nice ring as a metaphor. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermezzo):

> 1 :  a short light entr'acte
>
> 2 a:  a movement coming between the major sections of an extended musical work (as an opera) b :  a short independent instrumental composition
>
> 3 : a usually brief interlude or diversion

I had to look up [entr'acte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entr'acte) — that's "a dance, piece of music, or interlude performed between two acts of a play", or just the interval itself.

So, in any of these senses, this works very well if your intent is to imply that the *important* parts are off the edges, and this is just a temporary thing. For example:

- "Life is the *intermezzo* between birth and death; eternal reality is before and after."
- "He was in the *intermezzo* between knowledge and belief — he'd heard the news, but it hadn't really sunk in".
- "Act One was fear, and I hope Act Two will be love, but now, we are in a uncertain *intermezzo*."

Comment: _Intermezzo_ only works well if there is a suggestion of a transition, and while that presumably applies to _life–death_ it is not clear if he means it in that way in _fear–love_ or _knowing–believing_. _Intermezzo_ also carries a strong suggestion of a temporary state of affairs, rather than something to which one might return.

Comment: @PJTraill Agreed on all points.

Answer (score 0):

Interval. "time or space between" from the Latin, inter - between and vallum - a rampart. It will sound archaic but it is the right word according for the stated need.